# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение | PyQt и Socket

Tags: python, сокет, pyqt, asyncio, pyside

Пишу программу на Python с графическим интерфейсом. Которая передает камеру компьютера на другой ПК (Camera Streaming). Не знаю проблема ли в этом или нет, но мне кажется что я не правильно сделал асинхронность с PyQT и Socket.

**Код server.py:**

```
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QMenuBar,
    QSizePolicy, QStatusBar, QWidget)
from packages import *
from netsock import host
from wincom import write, read
from subprocess import Popen
from random import randint
from asyncio import get_event_loop, wait

from IPython.display import clear_output
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import numpy as np
import struct 
import zlib
from PIL import Image, ImageOps


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(385, 162)
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(u"favicon.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"QMainWindow {\n"
"   background-color: black;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLabel {\n"
"   color: white;\n"
"   font-family: \"Fira Code\", monospace;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"   color: white;\n"
"   background-color: #1E90FF;\n"
"   border-radius: 13px;\n"
"   font-size: 15px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   color: white;\n"
"   background-color: #1a7de0;\n"
"   border-radius: 13px;\n"
"   font-size: 15px;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(90, 10, 221, 51))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamilies([u"Fira Code"])
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(120, 50, 161, 31))
        font1 = QFont()
        font1.setFamilies([u"Fira Code"])
        font1.setPointSize(10)
        font1.setBold(False)
        font1.setItalic(False)
        self.label_2.setFont(font1)
        self.label_3 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(u"label_3")
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QRect(100, 110, 201, 31))
        font2 = QFont()
        font2.setFamilies([u"Fira Code"])
        font2.setPointSize(12)
        font2.setBold(False)
        font2.setItalic(False)
        self.label_3.setFont(font2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 385, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u" CameraShare - Waiting for clients", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Room address:", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"192.168.0.106:5555", None))
        self.label_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Waiting for user...", None))
    # retranslateUi

ip = read("address")
port = randint(1000, 9999)


async def window():

    app = QApplication([])
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    w = QMainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(w)
    w.show()

    ui.label_2.setText(f"{ip}:{port}")

    exit(app.exec())


async def network():

    HOST = ip
    PORT = port

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(10)

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    data = b""

    data = b""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize(">L")

    while True:
        while len(data) < payload_size:

            data += conn.recv(4096)

            if not data:
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                conn,addr=s.accept()
                continue


        packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
        data = data[payload_size:]
        msg_size = struct.unpack(">L", packed_msg_size)[0]

        while len(data) < msg_size:
            data += conn.recv(4096)

        frame_data = data[:msg_size]
        data = data[msg_size:]

        frame=pickle.loads(frame_data, fix_imports=True, encoding="bytes")
        frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        cv2.imshow('server',frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)



loop = get_event_loop()

application = loop.create_task(window())
socket_network = loop.create_task(network())

loop.run_until_complete(wait([application, socket_network]))
```

**Код client.py:**

```
import cv2
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import pickle
import numpy as np
import imutils


client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('192.168.0.105', 4387))

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img_counter = 0


encode_param=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),90]

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=320)
    frame = cv2.flip(frame,180)
    result, image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
    data = pickle.dumps(image, 0)
    size = len(data)

    if img_counter%10==0:
        client_socket.sendall(struct.pack(">L", size) + data)
        
    img_counter += 1

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    

cam.release()
```

**И также полная ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\CameraShare\client.py", line 12, in <module>
    client_socket.connect(('192.168.0.105', 4387))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
```

Comment: Что не понятного в ошибке "Конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение"? Как вообще это связано может быть с асинхронностью, камерой, и чем либо еще. Выкиньте вот весь код, оставьте только `client_socket.connect(('192.168.0.105', 4387))` и все связанное с подключением, получите тоже самое. Вы отправляете успешно запрос, но на стороне того, к кому этот запрос идет, есть проблемы с обработкой его (не открыт порт, не запущен сервер, фаервол, и прочее прочее прочее.).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я понял ошибку. Просто я не знаю как ее решить. Как бы я решил асихронность потому что я подумал модуль asyncio  не сработал и что функция `network()` не запустилась. И подумал что сервер из-за этого не запустился. Но сервер запускается порт открыт и все работает но с PyQt и Asyncio что-то не получается.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ и я был прав. Я сделал в функции `network()` команда которая будет писать в чат слово 1 (`print("1")`), но она не пишет ничего. И я понял что функция `network` в целом не загружается и значит ошибка в асинхронности и не правильно его вызвал.